# How can I with rabbitmqctl detect if a node is syncing queus?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have rabbitmq running in kubernetes.
When kubernetes for some reason wants to stop one of the rabbitmq nodes I want it to wait untill that node has finished synching its queues.

Does the command "rabbitmqctl stop_app" wait for queues to finish synching before it stops the node? or is there another way to implement a prestop script that waits for it?